How come when I plot the psd of a signal using welch the signal looks like it spans all frequencies instead of being a bump?
something like:
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import welch

#generate random bit string modulation

bits = np.random.randint(0,2,256)

#bits to bpsk symbols modulate

symbols = 2 * bits - 1 
#shift the frequency to desired location
freq_shift =2*np.pi*desired_frequency*time_vector
#create a carrier
carrier_w_signal = amplitude * np.cos(freq_shift*symbols)

frequencies, power = welch( carrier_w_signal , symbol_rate )

plot(frequencies, power)

when I do this the entire range of frequencies is the same power levelish instead of just at the specified frequency "desired_frequency" for example. I would expect the power to be higher around "desired_frequency". Why am I seeing this. Thanks!

Can you post pictures? Not at my computer right now.

Your code is incomplete and doesn't run. desired_frequency, time_vector and a few other things are not defined.

this is intentional as they are arbitrary/ you can set them to whatever

@maxtwente. I understand but best practice is to post complete code so we can reproduce the exact problem that you are having.

It appears that the OP is only simulating one sample per bit, with each sample represented as an impulse. In the PSD for a random modulated waveform you will see the PSD of each base pulse, in this case an impulse, so it is expected that you would see a flat PSD. The multiplication with the carrier simply circularly shifts the spectrum, so there will be no visible effect since the spectrum isn’t shaped.
The solution is to upsample the baseband waveform first, and this is typically combined with pulse shaping to properly restrict the spectrum. The Komm library in Python (which the OP is using) has support for this, so I recommend reviewing the examples from the library for more information (insert zeros to upsample to a higher sampling frequency and then pass that signal through the root-raised-cosine pulse shaping filter that is available in Komm). Also upsample to a rate that is much higher than the carrier frequency consistent with the Nyquist criteria.
The Welch method is an excellent choice for creating the PSD but many more samples are typically needed for an effective spectrum since it works by averaging multiple overlapped FFTs from the generated waveform. I recommend using at least $2^{18}$ samples and then also using the ‘nperseg’ parameter to modify the number of samples used in each FFT block that will be averaged. If the block size is increased there will be less blocks to average so more noise / variation in the overall result but higher resolution bandwidth: meaning able to make out more features in frequency and go lower in frequency closer to DC.
Below I demonstrate how I would do this in Python, if I needed to simulate a real passband signal (however the complex baseband signal already represents the complete spectrum and all of its properties, so there is no real need to actual simulate a passband signal). I did this with a QPSK signal to demonstrate the more general case of a complex baseband signal.

import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import komm

symbols = np.random.randint(0,4,2**18)
d = 1/np.sqrt(2)
constellation = np.array([d+1j*d, -d+1j*d, d-1j*d, -d-1j*d])
# map symbols to constellation 
baseband = constellation[symbols]

# zero insert upsample (10 samples per symbol)
rate = 10
baseband_upsampled = np.zeros(len(baseband) * rate, dtype='complex')
baseband_upsampled[::rate] = baseband

# pulse shaping filter (root raised cosine filter)
pulse = komm.RootRaisedCosinePulse(rolloff=0.25, length_in_symbols=16)
n = np.linspace(-8, 8, 16 * rate)
psf_coeff = pulse.impulse_response(n)
baseband_shaped = sig.lfilter(psf_coeff, np.sum(psf_coeff), baseband_upsampled)

# welch psd at baseband
faxis, psd_baseband = sig.welch(baseband_shaped, nperseg=2**12, return_onesided=False)

# upconvert to passband carrier
fc = 0.25
N = len(baseband_shaped)
n = np.arange(N)
passband = 2 * np.real(baseband_shaped * np.exp(1j* 2*np.pi *fc * n))

# welch psd at passband (real so could plot one-sided if desired)
faxis2, psd_passband = sig.welch(passband, nperseg=2**12, return_onesided=False)

Related: My “DSP for Software Radio” course details all the steps involved in doing this and more with specific demonstrations in Python using the same Komm library. Offered through https://dsprelated.com/courses and https://ieeeboston.org/courses/

Thank you Dan! this clears up some of my understanding. Do you know if the komm.pskmodulation(4).modulate() function would output the symbols or at the constellation step where you set "baseband". Also when you go to demodulate the baseband signal would one need to pass through another filter? rrcosfilter? or some kind of lowpass/notch? then call the komm.pskmodulation(4).demodulate() on that?

Also would one down sample somehow on the demodulation side

Hi Max -- I won't be able to provide a lengthy tutorial here which would really be necessary to properly answer your additional questions. Do consider the course I linked as I go into all those details there along with all the important caveats and more detailed explanation.
